# Flutter AndroidManifest.xml Error: package identifier or launch activity not found

Tags: android, flutter, dart, error-handling, manifest

I'm working on a Flutter project for Android and encountered an error related to the AndroidManifest.xml file. When trying to run my project, I receive the following error message:

```
package identifier or launch activity not found. Please check /Users/[user]/AndroidStudioProjects/[project]/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml for errors.
No application found for TargetPlatform.android_arm64.
Is your project missing an android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml? Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.
```

I've checked my AndroidManifest.xml, and it seems correct. The error persists even after ensuring that the package name and target platform are set correctly.

Can someone please provide guidance on how to resolve this issue? What could be causing this error, and what steps should I take to troubleshoot and fix it?

`AndroidManifest.xml:`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.webjow.hidden_gallery"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" />

    <application
        android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:fullBackupContent="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:manageSpaceActivity=".MainActivity"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:replace="android:label"
        tools:targetApi="34">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxx"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" />

        <activity-alias
            android:name="OneLauncherAlias"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>

        <activity-alias
            android:name="TwoLauncherAlias"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/calculator"
            android:label="@string/app_name_fake"
            android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Additional Information:**

Flutter version: `3.13.5` and Dart version: `3.1.2`

Comment: In place of this -> android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication" use this - android:name="${applicationName}"

Comment: @SanwalSingh my app need android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication".

Comment: Why you require this name?

Comment: @FaizAhmadDae can you provide a simple reproducible version showing this error?

Comment: can you try ```android:name=".MainActivity"``` to see if the error will persist

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have added multiple aliases that are targeting your Main Activity tag.

1. It can simply be resolved by removing both of the aliases.
2. Add the intent filter tag in the main activity tag and add a flag of exported true. This will solve the issue.

   ```
   <activity
           android:name=".MainActivity"
           android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme">
      <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
      </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   ```

Comment: I need the aliases bro.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

1. Remove `intent-filter` from both `activity-alias` and add that `intent-filter` inside the `activity`.
2. set `android:exported="true"` in the activity as well.

   ```
   <activity
       android:name=".MainActivity"
       android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" 
       android:exported="true"
       >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>

   <activity-alias
       android:name="OneLauncherAlias"
       android:enabled="true"
       android:exported="true"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
       android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" />

   <activity-alias
       android:name="TwoLauncherAlias"
       android:enabled="false"
       android:exported="true"
       android:icon="@mipmap/calculator"
       android:label="@string/app_name_fake"
       android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
       android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" />
   ```

Comment: this is work fine but my functionality is not working with your code. such as changing the app icons and app name.

Comment: what procedure are you following for changing app icons and app name?

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate `<activity-alias>` Elements:
you have defined two `<activity-alias>` elements. This is typically not required. You should only have one `<activity-alias>` to define the launcher activity.

Remove either the `"OneLauncherAlias"` or `"TwoLauncherAlias"` `<activity-alias>` based on your requirements. The launcher alias should define the entry point of your app.

after that it looks like

```
           <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="com.webjow.hidden_gallery"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
            
            <!-- Your permissions, application, and meta-data here -->

            <application
                android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
                android:allowBackup="false"
                android:fullBackupContent="false"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:manageSpaceActivity=".MainActivity"
                android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
                android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
                tools:replace="android:label"
                tools:targetApi="34">
            
                <!-- Your activities and other components here -->

                <meta-data
                    android:name="flutterEmbedding"
                    android:value="2" />
            </application>
        </manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

Check if `namespace "com.webjow.hidden_gallery"` is in your `app/build.gradle`

Here essentially

```
android {
   namespace "com.webjow.hidden_gallery"
   compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
   ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
```